# How to determine the revision from which current Mono runtime was built and installed?

Tags: mono, version

I want to determine the revision (how to call properly it in Git?) from which current Mono runtime was built and installed.

```
$ dmcs --version
Mono C# compiler version 2.9.0.0
```

but it's definitely insufficient.

XSP/ASP.NET error page gives more information:

> Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.8.1 (master/cdf1247 Sat Sep 4 01:22:04 MSD 2010); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1

but it seems to be a dirty hack to me.

How to do it properly?

Comment: For bonus points, anyone know how to determine which version of Mono is included with the Unity game engine? In Unity 4.1.5 the techniques shown here give me "version 2.0", though I have reason to believe it's version 2.8.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mono -V` will output the version string, including source code revision.

Answer (score 17):

If you're looking for the mono runtime version; there is an internal Mono.Runtime class in mscorlib, it has a static method GetDisplayName which should return a string with current runtime version. This method is private but still can be accessed via reflection. I wrote a small script to test this, check if would work for you:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime");
if (type != null)
{                                          
    MethodInfo dispalayName = type.GetMethod("GetDisplayName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static); 
    if (dispalayName != null)                   
        Console.WriteLine(dispalayName.Invoke(null, null)); 
}
```

on my system this returns:

> 2.6.7 (Debian 2.6.7-3ubuntu1~dhx1)

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how can I get a message like `(master/cdf1247 Sat Sep 4 01:22:04 MSD 2010)`?

Comment: You get that if your mono was built from a git checkout, a build from a tarball will get you just the version.