# Programmatically determining Mono runtime version

Tags: c#, .net, mono

**What is the recommended way to determine the Mono runtime version programmatically?**

We have encountered various problems when our .Net application is used with older versions of Mono.  Sometimes we can work around these problems, if we know which version we are dealing with, but sometimes we can't.

The solution for us would be to detect the Mono version programmatically, and then we can transparently apply the workarounds.  If the Mono version is too old, then we would prompt the user to upgrade.

We can discover that Mono is our runtime with something like this:

```
bool isMonoRuntime = Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null;
```

How can we also determine reliably the mono version without inferring it indirectly?  To be clear, we need the Mono release number, not the .Net CLR version number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the revision from which current Mono runtime was built and installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178129/how-to-determine-the-revision-from-which-current-mono-runtime-was-built-and-inst)

Comment: @skilima The key difference is that asks for a command-line-based approach, and this question asks for a programmatical approach.  there is some duplication in one answer, but that answer is much more suited to this question than that!

Comment: Bonus points to any answer that doesn't rely on reflection! (As a purely academic challenge.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can check the mono runtime version as:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime");
if (type != null)
{
    MethodInfo displayName = type.GetMethod("GetDisplayName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    if (displayName != null)
        Console.WriteLine(displayName.Invoke(null, null));
}
```

Check this [How to determine the revision from which current Mono runtime was built and installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178129/how-to-determine-the-revision-from-which-current-mono-runtime-was-built-and-inst) for more details.

Comment: Not quite perfect because the string is not uniformly formatted across different builds, but close enough for our purposes, I think.  Thanks.

Comment: What namespace is `BindingFlags` in?

Comment: @AaronFranke: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=xamarinios-10.8

Comment: @AaronFranke `System.Reflection`, as far as I know

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution (without using reflection)

```
[DllImport("__Internal", EntryPoint="mono_get_runtime_build_info")]
public extern static string GetMonoVersion();


Console.WriteLine("Mono version: {0}",GetMonoVersion());
Mono version: 3.12.0 (tarball Sat Feb  7 19:13:43 UTC 2015)
```

Comment: To get DllImport, you must include:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Comment: Will this crash if not running under mono?

Comment: What namespace is `DllImport` from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ImageRuntimeVersion
```

It should give you the Mono CLR version, and as a bonus it will give you the CLR version on Windows.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.imageruntimeversion.aspx

Comment: That gives the CLR version, not the Mono version, unfortunately.

Comment: Presumably, System.Environment.Version is simpler for that anyway?

Comment: Apparantly you can use reflection to access `Mono.Runtime.GetDisplayName()`. It's a private method that returns a string like *"Mono 1.2.6"*.